# Please explain the SET Option Requirements for computed columns

Tags: sql-server

[Creating Indexes on Computed Columns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189292.aspx) contains a list of six SET options that must be ON and one that must be OFF when using computed columns in an index.

Why must they be set this way?

Answer (score 1):

Because you dont want computed columns to be any more expensive than possible, and would you rather have one, tightly written and tested code path responsible for them, or 128 different code paths (2^7 combinations of options).

They allow the developers of this code to just assume these things are so.

Answer (score 0):

Hm, do you need any more reasons apart from that SQL Server requires them for the statement to succeed? :-)

No, seriously. Because different SET options can affect the result, I guess they must be set this way to ensure that all connections do see the same computed values.

Comment: Yep. I'd like a better reason than "just because" :-)

Comment: Guess in that case you'd have to ask the SQL Server storage engine guys. :-)

Comment: Just found this one: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175088.aspx. Maybe this is "good enough"?